# Firefox losing focus on textareas

Tags: firefox

Since yesterday, while typing, Firefox 3.5 on my laptop running Ubuntu Linux x64 has been losing focus on various fields from textareas on webpages, to the address and search bars. It's not that it thinks the <kbd>tab</kbd> key is being pressed because it's not going to anywhere, it's just unfocusing everything. It's also not a hardware problem, as other applications are not affected.

Add ons (all listed but they've been there since before the problem started):

- Adblock Plus
- Delicious Bookmarks
- Downlod Statusbar
- Firebug
- Stylish
- Google Gears
- FireFTP
- Nightly Tester Tools
- All in One Sidebar
- Tab Mix Plus
- DownloadHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling all add-ons/running in safe mode didn't work. I eventually solved the problem by reinstalling Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Did any of the add-ons update just before the problem started? If not this then something else must have changed in your set up to cause the problem.

I would be simple to eliminate them as a possibility by running Firefox in safe mode or by disabling them all.

If the problem still occurs, then it's something else that's changed recently. If not then add the plugins back in one at a time until it does and you should have your culprit. The only other thing that might cause the problem is an interaction between the plugins.